# Install apt package in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I have mistakenly removed the default package APT from my system .

When I run command `locate apt-get`, I get below output:

```
/home/jeet/apt-get
/home/jeet/Desktop/apt/apt-0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13/cmdline/apt-get.cc
/home/jeet/Desktop/apt/apt-0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13/doc/apt-get.8.xml
/home/jeet/Desktop/apt/apt-0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13/doc/de/apt-get.de.8
/home/jeet/Desktop/apt/apt-0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13/doc/fr/apt-get.fr.8
/home/jeet/Desktop/apt/apt-0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13/doc/ja/apt-get.ja.8
/home/jeet/Downloads/apt-get
/home/jeet/Downloads/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
```

If I run `ls | grep apt-get`, then I won't get any output.

Can anybody please advice how to recover apt package or install it from start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the apt .deb package, depending on your system, from the following locations. Once downloaded, open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>) and run the appropriate commands indicated below.

**Downloading apt for 12.04:**

The 32-bit version of apt can be [downloaded here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10_i386.deb).

To install:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10_i386.deb
```

For the 64-bit version:
[download here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10_amd64.deb)

To install:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10_amd64.deb
```

**Downloading apt for 12.10:**

The 32-bit version of apt can be [downloaded here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5.4_i386.deb).

To install:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5.4_i386.deb
```

For the 64-bit version:
[download here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb).

To install:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from `Ubuntu Software Center`.

Enter `apt` in the search box, it should come-up as the first option, simply install it.

Comment: Simplistic!! and thorough

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue. To resolve this I downloaded apt deb file from below URL.
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/

and installed it using dpkg -i filename.deb

and apt-get was back in place!!

Comment: I fail to see what this answer adds to the one already given?